# react native share dynamic link

Tags: firebase, react-native, facebook-messenger

1.Everything work fine before share, I shared to `Facebook Messenger` and click the social content, the redirect link is not the link that `firebase` generated. The link has become the `dynamic domain` mixed with the `title` and `description`.

2.I tried to copy only the generated `firebase` link and paste to `Facebook Messenger`, social content loaded, then by clicking the content it call the dynamic link correctly and launch the app.

```
const link =  new firebase.links.DynamicLink('https://example.com/parameter' , 'abc123.app.goo.gl')
.android.setPackageName('com.example.android')
.ios.setBundleId('com.example.android')
.social.setTitle("Social Title")
.social.setImageUrl("http://exmaple.com/super.png")
.social.setDescriptionText("Description");

firebase.links().createShortDynamicLink(link, 'SHORT')
.then((url) => {
  Share.share({
    message: "Message Title",
    url: url,
    title: "Title"
  }, {
    // Android only:
    dialogTitle: 'Super Share'
  })
  // ...
});
```

How to share with correct dynamic link not just copy and paste, consider the user behavior.